# JavaScript console function giving different output

Tags: javascript

When I am trying to output something with console.log() function its give me correct output but suddenly when I provide 033 as an input to the function it's give me the output as 027. Can anybody explain me why it is happen in java script.

Comment: under the hood `console.log` is using parseInt: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 2):

033 is recognized as a number in octal system:

```
01 = 1
010 = 8
033 = 27
```

[Octal system on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal)